# jxbrowser re-creation rises a dialog opens "Your profile could not be opened correctly"

Tags: javafx, jxbrowser

After jxbrowser disposal and re-creation a dialog opens:
"Your profile could not be opened correctly".

OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.3 (16D32)

jxbrowser version: 6.14.2

mode: lightweight/heavyweight.

Console contains errors related to sqlite database lock:

```
[0730/144906:ERROR:connection.cc(1892)] Passwords sqlite error 5, errno 0: database is locked, sql: PRAGMA auto_vacuum
[0730/144906:ERROR:connection.cc(1892)] Passwords sqlite error 5, errno 0: database is locked, sql: PRAGMA journal_mode = TRUNCATE
[0730/144906:ERROR:connection.cc(1892)] History sqlite error 5, errno 0: database is locked, sql: COMMIT
[0730/144906:INFO:main-delegate.cpp(65)] Executable name: /private/var/folders/95/mcf0whns7vn3kckjk3z3q_b80000gq/T/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.2/jxbrowser-chromium.app/Contents/Frameworks/jxbrowser-chromium-helper.app/Contents/MacOS/jxbrowser-chromium-helper
[0730/144906:INFO:main-delegate.cpp(80)] Frameworks path: /private/var/folders/95/mcf0whns7vn3kckjk3z3q_b80000gq/T/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.2/jxbrowser-chromium.app/Contents/Frameworks
[0730/144906:INFO:main-delegate.cpp(65)] Executable name: /private/var/folders/95/mcf0whns7vn3kckjk3z3q_b80000gq/T/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.2/jxbrowser-chromium.app/Contents/Frameworks/jxbrowser-chromium-helper.app/Contents/MacOS/jxbrowser-chromium-helper
[0730/144906:INFO:main-delegate.cpp(80)] Frameworks path: /private/var/folders/95/mcf0whns7vn3kckjk3z3q_b80000gq/T/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.2/jxbrowser-chromium.app/Contents/Frameworks
[0730/144906:INFO:main-delegate.cpp(65)] Executable name: /private/var/folders/95/mcf0whns7vn3kckjk3z3q_b80000gq/T/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.2/jxbrowser-chromium.app/Contents/Frameworks/jxbrowser-chromium-helper.app/Contents/MacOS/jxbrowser-chromium-helper
[0730/144906:INFO:main-delegate.cpp(80)] Frameworks path: /private/var/folders/95/mcf0whns7vn3kckjk3z3q_b80000gq/T/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.2/jxbrowser-chromium.app/Contents/Frameworks
[0730/144907:ERROR:connection.cc(1892)] Passwords sqlite error 5, errno 0: database is locked, sql: PRAGMA cache_size=32
[0730/144907:ERROR:connection.cc(1892)] Passwords sqlite error 5, errno 0: database is locked, sql: SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type=? AND name=? COLLATE NOCASE
[0730/144907:ERROR:connection.cc(1892)] Passwords sqlite error 5, errno 0: database is locked, sql: SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type=? AND name=? COLLATE NOCASE
[0730/144907:ERROR:connection.cc(1892)] Passwords sqlite error 5, errno 0: database is locked, sql: CREATE TABLE meta(key LONGVARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, value LONGVARCHAR)
[0730/144907:ERROR:login_database.cc(542)] Unable to create the meta table.
[0730/144907:ERROR:password_store_proxy_mac.cc(84)] Could not create/open login database.
[0730/144908:ERROR:cookie_monster.cc(1539)] Found 1 duplicate cookies for host='google.ru', with {name='NID', domain='.google.ru', path='/'}
```

Very similar bugs were closed in previous chromium versions:

1. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=532555
2. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=344358

but suggested workarounds with settings "--password-store=basic" or "--password-store=default" don't work.

Comment: When you dispose all JxBrowser instances, all jxbrowser-chromium processes should be completed. This issue might happen if some of jxbrowser-chromium processes didn't stop properly.
Could you please dispose JxBrowser instance and check in the process manager if it still contains jxbrowser-chromium process?

Comment: Yes, in case when I initialize only one browser the whole process looks like:
1. On app start I initialize browser core and set logs directory. The first jxbrowser-chromium-helper process starts.
2. After that I add the first browser instance to the app, the second jxbrowser-chromium-helper starts.
3. When I dispose the browser added in p.2, the first process still work.

4. When I add new instance instead of disposed - dialog with error opens.

5. When I close the app, all jxbrowser-chromium-helper processes stop.

Comment: The same code on Windows 10 leads to app freeze right after disposal, meanwhile 3 jxbrowser-chromium-helper is run. If cancel some of them - application unfreezes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jxbrowser-chromium-helper process blocks the browser context directory after disposal. If the next browser instance is created with its own BrowserContext instance configured to the same directory, this leads to the concurrent access to the same data.
Please try using the same BrowserContext instance for all Browser instances.